# Query to check if MySQL database is connected

Tags: mysql, sql, select, health-monitoring

I am wondering if there is a best practice or standard query used to check if a MySQL database is still connected?

I was originally thinking of performing a simple search in one of my tables, which will confirm if the database is still there. Just wondering if there is a better approach.

Comment: Note that it's considered a bad practice to test your database connectivity in a health check, if you're working in a containerized environment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need to actually `select` from a table. You could just do:

```
select 1
```

This is a very cheap query, that will error if the database is not connected. The `1` does not really matter (the important point is to not have a `from` clause). You could as well use `select null`, or `select 'foo'`.